# Cannot query a sum and compare the sum with another total in a mysql query

Tags: mysql, linux, sum

I want to check 2 databases to see if the money-payments are the same as the total. That is possible, but I get a very long table:

```
select 
  transaction_id
  ,total_low+total_high a
  , sum(money_received) b 
from 
  archive_transaction inner join archive_transaction_payment 
    on archive_transaction.id=archive_transaction_payment.transaction_id 
group by transaction_id;
```

Actually I only want the transactions where the total is wrong!!
So now I want to add a!=b and that gives an invalid query. How to proceed?
Table archive_transaction has 1 row per transaction, but archive_transaction_payment can have multiple payments for one transaction. This makes it complicated for me.

```
select 
  transaction_id
  ,total_low+total_high a
  , sum(money_received) b 
from archive_transaction inner join archive_transaction_payment 
       on archive_transaction.id=archive_transaction_payment.transaction_id 
where 
  a!=b 
group by transaction_id;
```

Comment: Does `HAVING a != b` work?

Comment: Could you please add a dbfiddle example because of  https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Are you aware of the difference between a database and a table? And see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Unless every(ie the same) transaction_id always exists in both table it's unsafe to join the tables in this way.

Comment: For this database every table starts with an id column.... but actually, the id in archive_transaction is the transaction_id. Therefore I can join these tables. Maybe I should reconsider this.

Answer (score 0):

Joins are still problematic for me, but I found an answer without join to find faults in the database.

```
SELECT id
FROM   archive_transaction a
WHERE  total_low + total_high != (SELECT Sum(money_received)
                                  FROM   archive_transaction_payment b
                                  WHERE  a.id = b.transaction_id);
```

Now I get a short list of problems in my database. Thanks for helping me out.